# Stack Bar Grapth with plot / pandas

Tags: python, plot

I am not being able to generate a stacked graph with the error below:

```
TypeError: There is no Line2D property "stacked"
```

My csv has the format:

```
feb-17,1,2,3
apr-17,2,4,3
may-18,3,5,3
oct-20,4,1,1
dec-21,5,1,1
```

I would expect to see something like:

[image]

My code is:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pandas.read_csv(datacsv.csv, delimiter=',', 
                 index_col=0, 
                 parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True, 
                 names=['Date','Black','Red', 'Yellow'])

df.plot(Stacked=True, marker='.',markersize=8, title ="My graph", fontsize = 10, color=['b','g','c'], figsize=(15, 15))

imagepathprotocol = "image.png"

plt.savefig(imagepathprotocol)
```

Any idea what can be done? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code

```
df.plot(stacked=True,kind ='bar',title ="My graph",fontsize =10,color=['b','g','c'], figsize=(15, 15))
```

you need to point out the bar kind and delete the marker/markersize

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the correct direction. Actually kind= bar didnt work but the following worked: df.plot.bar(stacked=True, title ="My graph", fontsize = 10, color=['b','g','c'], figsize=(15, 15))

Comment: “df.plot.bar()” should be equivalent to “df.plot(kind='bar')”
it worked in my IDE

Comment: I know.. not sure why here I get an error. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change the type -

```py
df.plot.bar(stacked=True, marker='.',markersize=8, title ="My graph", fontsize = 10, color=['b','g','c'], figsize=(15, 15))
```

By default it tries to plot a 2D line and this indeed does not have a stacked option.

See documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#bar-plots)